# Register and load scripts

Tags: functions, wp-enqueue-script

In my  `functions.php`

```
    function load_scripts() 
        {
 wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
wp_register_script( 'modernizr', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/modernizr.foundation.js' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'modernizr' );
wp_register_script( 'jquery.simpleWeather', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/jquery.simpleWeather.js', array( 'jquery'));
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.simpleWeather' );
        }
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts ');
```

I try to register and load scripts to my wp theme. For `jquery.simpleWeather.js` i have a part of code that load in the `header.php`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.simpleWeather({
zipcode: '',
woeid: '',
location: '',
unit: 'f',
success: function(weather) {
html = '<span>'+weather.city+', '+weather.region+'</span>';
html += '<img style="float:left;" width="125px" src="'+weather.image+'">';
html += '<p>'+weather.temp+'&deg; '+weather.units.temp+'<br /></p>';
$(".weather").html(html);
},
error: function(error) {
$(".weather").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
}
}); 
</script>
```

Also i edit the code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$.simpleWeather({    
zipcode: '',    
woeid: '',   
location: '',   
unit: 'f',   
success: function(weather) {
html = '<span>'+weather.city+', '+weather.region+'</span>';
html += '<img style="float:left;" width="125px" src="'+weather.image+'">';
html += '<p>'+weather.temp+'&deg; '+weather.units.temp+'<br /></p>';
$(".weather").html(html);    
},
error: function(error) {    
$(".weather").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
} 
});    
</script>
```

But the scripts didn't register and load. Any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `if ( !is_admin() )`. `wp_enqueue_scripts` only runs on the front end.

WordPress loads jQuery in ["No Conflict" mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). The `$` alias does not work. Use `jQuery` or wrap your script is a function as demonstrated in the jQuery docs:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($){
  $(function() { 
   // more code using $ as alias to jQuery
  });
})(jQuery);
```

You claim that your script loads after jQuery but I don't see that it loads at all, and certainly not after jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- missing jquery.simpleWeather.js -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$.simpleWeather({
```

Your `jquery.simpleWeather.js` has to load at the line marked in the code or your attempt to use it in the following line will fail, but there is no sign of that script. If it has loaded, it loaded before jQuery, which will also fail since it is a jQuery plugin and is dependent upon jQuery.

Also, I get an 'invalid callback' error with your code. I don't know why. It looks fine. Possibly there is some oddball character in the code somewhere. I had to completely rewrite the function to get it working. If you can't get this working copy the following code.

```
function load_my_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
  wp_register_script( 'modernizr', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/modernizr.foundation.js' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'modernizr' );
  wp_register_script( 'jquery.simpleWeather', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/jquery.simpleWeather.js', array( 'jquery'));
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.simpleWeather' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','load_my_scripts');
```

Somewhat off-topic but what software are you using to edit this code?

Comment: You don't need the `jQuery.noConflict()`-- that is directly from the jQuery docs. Is your script loading ***after*** both jQuery and simpleWeather?

Comment: yes the script load after jQuery.

Comment: Any solution? i am try to edit and add the code, but the result is the same. I know that the choice that i have made, maybe is not the best, but if i leave it as it is, I will have some delay in disengagement or code? When i refresh the page (local environment) i notice that the weather.js has delay. Thanks again

Comment: Where is your opening `<script>` tag? Please edit your question with new information. Code is nearly unreadable in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
header.php
```

....

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); ?> 
.....
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$.simpleWeather({
zipcode: '',
woeid: '',
location: '',
unit: '',
success: function(weather) {
html = '<h6>'+weather.city+', '+weather.region+'</h6>';
html += '<img style="float:left;" width="125px" src="'+weather.image+'">';
html += '<p>'+weather.temp+'&deg; '+weather.units.temp+'<br /></p>';
$(".weather").html(html);
},
error: function(error) {
$(".weather").html('<p>'+error+'</p>');
}
}); 
});
</script>
```

in the `functions.php`

```
function load_my_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
wp_register_script( 'modernizr', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/modernizr.foundation.js' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'modernizr' );
wp_register_script( 'jquery.simpleWeather', get_template_directory_uri() .'/js/jquery.simpleWeather.js', array( 'jquery'));
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.simpleWeather' );}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','load_my_scripts');?>
```

and works, Thanks for the feedback.